# ASP.NET Menu Control: 1st level static, second level dynamic, third level static

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, controls

so here's my problem:

I have a menu control on my website which gets its data from a xml file. I need the first level to be static and the second to be dynamic, so far so good. But there is one more level that needs to be static as well!

Since you can set the maximum number of static/dynamic levels but NOT the property for every level specifically, is there any way to accomplish what I am looking for?

Comment: Could you post the code you are working with? And errors you are receiving?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Kettic Menu Controls for Windows Forms](http://www.kettic.com/winforms_ui/csharp_guide/menu_get_started.shtml) can fully customize item appearance, text, orientation, image, checkbox, and any other controls at design time.